# Ĉu prepozicioj estas plifortaj ol akuzativo?

Tags: accusative

> Kiom da seĝoj vi havas hejme?
>   Ĉu vi trinkis multe da lakto?

Saluton. En la frazoj, seĝoj kaj lakto estas la direktaj objektoj. Mi scias ke oni ne aldonas akuzativon al "kiom da" kaj "multe da", sed kial oni ne aldonas akuzativon al la direktaj objektoj? (*kiom da seĝojN / multe da laktoN*) **Ĉu nur pro ke tiuj vortoj estas prepozicioj kaj la venontaj vortoj ne povas havi akuzativon?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oni ne povas konkludi, ke prepozicioj estas pli fortaj ol akuzativo aŭ aliflanke.

Nuntempe oni uzas la prepozicion "da" kun vortoj, kiuj montras amason (kiom, tiom, multe…), sed tiel ne estis komence kaj oni diris

- Kiom seĝojn vi havas hejme?
- Ĉu vi trinkis multan lakton?

Ial oni forlasis tiun kutimon kaj nuntempe diras kun la prepozicio "da".

Rigardu

[Why did "kiom", "tiom", "iom" etc. without "da" fall out of fashion?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/why-did-kiom-tiom-iom-etc-without-da-fall-out-of-fashion)

[How to mark accusative for correlatives of quantity? Kiel marki akuzativon ĉe "...iom"-aj tabelvortoj?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/how-to-mark-accusative-for-correlatives-of-quantity-kiel-marki-akuzativon-%C4%89e)

Comment: Dankegon pro via utila respondo, Sinjoro Metsäkallas. Tio estas tre interesa historia fakto, kaj laŭ mi l'antaŭa maniero estas plibela kaj plilogika (Laŭ mi, la nuntempa maniero estas pli laŭlingva ol laŭlogika).

Answer (score 2):

Ĝenerale oni metas la akuzativon sur la rektan objekton en la frazo. Plejofte, la vorto post prepozicio havas alian rolon ol la objekton. Tio validas ankaŭ por viaj ekzemplaj frazoj. En la unua frazo *kiom* estas la objekto, kaj *da seĝoj* nur priskribas la objekton sed ne estas la objekto mem. Pro tio oni ne povas aldoni la akuzativon al ĝi. La afero estas pli klara en aliaj frazoj kie la vorto kiun *da* priskribas ja povas havi la akuzativon:

> Li manĝis manplenon da vinberoj.

Tie, *manpleno* estas kvanto kaj ĝi estas la rekta objekto. *Vinberoj* estas nur priskribo  de la kvanto. Estus strange meti la akuzativon sur ambaŭ vortojn.

Tamen, por kelkaj prepozicioj la vorto post ĝi ja povas roli kiel la objekto. Ekzemple:

> Ili manĝis po unu pomo.

Tiuokaze, *unu pomo* ja rolas kiel la objekto. Estas debateble ĉu oni povas meti la akuzativon tie. Mi kredas ke plejofte oni ne metas ĝin.

Comment: Dankon Sinjoro Roberts pro via respondo. Vi menciis interesan fakton.